# Node.js express, routers and compression

Tags: node.js, express, http-compression

In a Node.js application based on express I load the compression middleware this way:

```
const express = require("express");
const compression = require("compression");
const app = express();
app.use(compression());
```

If I add a router to manage API requests should I load again compression in the router or its responses are already compressed?

```
const router = express.Router();
router.use(compression()); // Is this needed or not?

router.get(...); // and all other API methods
app.use("/api", router);

app.use("/", express.static("./pages"));
```

Thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 5):

No, you don't have to load the `compression` middleware into specific routes if you load it into your app.

- Any middleware you load into your app will apply to all routes. These are [application-level middleware](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html#middleware.application).

  `app.use(middleware)`
- Any middleware you use for specific routes will not apply for any other route. These are [router-level middleware](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html#middleware.router).

  `router.get('/route', middleware, ...)`

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to load compression again.

From [compression npm examples](https://www.npmjs.com/package/compression#examples)

> **express/connect**
>
> When using this module with express or connect, simply app.use the
>   module as high as you like. Requests that pass through the middleware
>   will be compressed.
>
> ```
> var compression = require('compression')
> var express = require('express')
>
> var app = express()
>
> // compress all responses
> app.use(compression())
>
> // add all routes
> ```